# How to install python package in powershell with neovim?

Tags: python, powershell, neovim

I am a total beginner to coding in general.
What does the error mean, can someone explain?

[Executing Installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LujMq.png)

[After Pressing Enter/Confirm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bccYi.png)

nvim main.py - I tried it, but got this error - "coc.python item.dispose is not a function"

Comment: Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask]

Answer (score 0):

The error's related to the `coc-python` extension, to fix it try running these commands:

`:CocInstall coc-python`

Or if you already have it installed:
`:CocUpdate coc-python`

If this doesn't work, maybe try uninstalling and reinstalling, or disabling and reenabling